# Being $z=x+yi$ how can I factorize the polynomial $z^4+1$ as a product of real quadratic polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, factoring

Being $z=x+yi$ how can I factorize the polynomial $z^4+1$ as a product of real quadratic polynomials?

---

I don't really understand what I am asked to do. How can I start with it?

Comment: Can you factorise it as a product of complex linear polynomials?

Comment: How can I do that? @AnginaSeng

Comment: Hint : $(z^2+\alpha z +1)(z^2-\alpha z +1)$ ... $ \alpha=?$

Comment: And if I've got the polynomial $z^6+1$ ? @DonaldSplutterwit

Comment: Similar question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841247/being-z-xyi-how-can-i-factorize-the-polynomial-zn1-as-a-product-of-real-q

Comment: The examples you have are relatively easy ones to which some neat tricks can be supplied, but the general way of identifying the quadratic factors involves noticing first that the roots of the polynomial lie evenly distributed on the unit circle and can be explicitly identified using the exponential form of complex numbers; and second that the complex conjugate pairs of roots are therefore easy to identify; and third that the sum of two complex conjugate numbers of this form can be expressed in terms of the cosine. (product is easy). In your examples the cosines can be computed directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the other answers but prefer an intuitive approach,
which uses the idea that $e^{(i\theta)} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.

You want all values $e^{(i\alpha)}$ such that 
$\left[e^{(i\alpha)}\right]^4 = e^{(i4\alpha)} = -1
= e^{(i\pi)}.$

The easiest way to do that is to **pretend** that 
$e^{(i\pi)}$ can actually be represented by
the 4 elements $\{e^{(i\pi)}, e^{(i3\pi)}, e^{(i5\pi)}, e^{(i7\pi)}\}.$

Then, with the argument of each of the 4 elements divided by 4, 
you see that the 4 distinct roots are 
$\{e^{(i\pi/4)}, e^{(i3\pi/4)}, e^{(i5\pi/4)}, e^{(i7\pi)/4}\}.$

Having identified the 4 roots, you need to combine them into
conjugate pairs, and then use each pair of roots to form a
quadratic.

This results in $\left[\left(z - e^{(i\pi/4)}\right)
\left(z - e^{(i7\pi/4)}\right)\right] \times
\left[\left(z - e^{(i3\pi/4)}\right)
\left(z - e^{(i5\pi/4)}\right)\right]
$

$=\left[
\left(z - \langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle\right)
\left(z - \langle\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle\right)
\right]$

$\times
\left[
\left(z - \langle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle\right)
\left(z - \langle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} - i\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle\right)
\right]
$

$= \left(z^2 -\sqrt{2}z + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right) \times
\left(z^2 +\sqrt{2}z + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)
$

$= \left(z^2 -\sqrt{2}z + 1\right) \times
\left(z^2 +\sqrt{2}z + 1\right)
$

$= (z^4 + 1).$

**Addendum**
Per OP's request : attacking $(z^6 + 1) = 0.$

As in the original answer, **pretend** that 
$e^{(i\pi)}$ can actually be represented by
the **6** elements $\{e^{(i\pi)}, e^{(i3\pi)}, e^{(i5\pi)}, e^{(i7\pi)}, e^{(i9\pi)}, e^{(i11\pi)}\}.$

Then, with the argument of each of the 6 elements divided by 6, 
you see that the 6 distinct roots are 
$\{e^{(i\pi/6)}, e^{(i3\pi/6)}, e^{(i5\pi/6)}, e^{(i7\pi)/6}, e^{(i9\pi/6)}, e^{(i11\pi)/6}\}.$

Having identified the 6 roots, you need to combine them into
conjugate pairs, and then use each pair of roots to form a
quadratic.

This results in $\left[\left(z - e^{(i\pi/6)}\right)
\left(z - e^{(i11\pi/6)}\right)\right]$

$\times
\left[\left(z - e^{(i3\pi/6)}\right)
\left(z - e^{(i9\pi/6)}\right)\right]
$

$\times
\left[\left(z - e^{(i5\pi/6)}\right)
\left(z - e^{(i7\pi/6)}\right)\right].
$

The rest of the conversion into real quadratics would follow
the same method as in the original answer, simply multiplying everything out.

What makes this answer convenient is that all 6 roots of 
$\left[e^{i\pi}\right]^{(1/6)}$ are special angles 
each of whose sin and cosine key off of 
$e^{(i\pi/6)}.$

Answer (score 2):

I think, the following is better. $$z^4+1=z^4+2z^2+1-2z^2=(z^2+1)^2-(\sqrt2z)^2=$$
$$=(z^2-\sqrt2z+1)(z^2+\sqrt2z+1).$$

Also, $$z^6+1=(z^2+1)(z^4-z^2+1)=(z^2+1)((z^2+1)^2-3z^2)=$$
$$=(z^2+1)(z^2-\sqrt3z+1)(z^2+\sqrt3z+1).$$

Comment: And if I've got the polynomial $z^6+1$ ?

Comment: what? how can I do it? @user2661923

Comment: @User160  For $z^6+1$ there is a similar way.

Comment: which way exactly? @MichaelRozenberg

Comment: @User160  See my post. We can get a factoring of $z^6+1$ by the same way.

Comment: I've understood what you've done but this time I don't know how to solve it

Comment: @User160  I added something. See now.

Comment: But how do you know that? You try with different numbers until it reach the solutions? Or does come up to you that you have to use those numbers?

Comment: @User160 I used $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2),$ $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b).$

Answer (score 0):

So you understood the hint
\begin{eqnarray*}
(z^2+\alpha z +1)(z^2-\alpha z +1)=z^4+\underbrace{(2-\alpha^2)}_{2-\alpha^2=0}z^2+1.
\end{eqnarray*}
To do the next one in your comment ... Factorise $z^6+1=(z^2+1)(z^4-z^2+1)$
\begin{eqnarray*}
(z^2+\alpha z +1)(z^2-\alpha z +1)=z^4+\underbrace{(2-\alpha^2)}_{2-\alpha^2=-1}z^2+1.
\end{eqnarray*}
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
z^6+1=(z^2+1)(z^2+\sqrt{3}z+1)(z^2-\sqrt{3}z+1).
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

***Direct factorization*** treating imaginary $ (i^2=-1) $ number algebraically

$$ z^4+1= (z^2-i)(z^2+i)=(z-\sqrt i)(z+\sqrt i)(z-i\sqrt i)(z+i\sqrt i)$$

The arguments in the complex plane are odd multiples of $\pi/4$ because exponent directly multiplies/divides the argument, tips of radius vector are at $ (2k-1) \pi/2$ on unit circle.

[image]

If $\sin \pi/4=  \cos \pi/4=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}=q,\;$ then the four factors are
$$=(z+(-1-q))(z+(-1+q))(z+(1-q))(z+(1+q)).$$

The equation is encountered as elastic foundation ode for plates.