# Being $z=x+yi$ how can I factorize the polynomial $z^n+1$ as a product of real quadratic polynomials?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Being $z=x+yi$ how can I factorize the polynomial $z^n+1$ as a product of real quadratic polynomials?

---

I don't know how to start with it, which is the general formula for doing this type of exercise?

Comment: Basically the roots are odd powers of $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n}}$, and you pair off each factor $Z-\omega$ with the factor $Z- \omega^{-1}$ to get a real factor.

Comment: What? I don't understand what you are saying @ancientmathematician can you explain me in another way, please?

Comment: Comment: as stated the result is false when $n$ is odd; in that case there is also the linear factor $Z+1$.

Comment: @QED beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

$-1=\exp(i\pi)$. So roots of the equation $z^n+1$ are $\exp(i\theta)$ for $\theta\in\{\frac{\pi (2k+1)}{n}|k=1,\cdots n\}$. We know the complex roots of an equation appear in conjugate pairs. So if $\omega$ is one of the roots then so is $\bar{\omega}$. Note that for any two conjugate complex numbers $a$ and $\bar{a}$, we have $(z-a)(z-\bar{a})=z^2-2\mathrm{Re}(a)z+|a|^2$, which is a real quadratic equation.

Comment: @User160 Assuming that $n ~\in ~\mathbb{Z^+}~$ QED's answer means that the factorization into real quadratic polynomials is do-able if and only if $n$ is even.  In fact, QED's answer provides the complete method, when $n$ is even.  The explicit details, re $n=4$ or $n=6$ are given at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3841199/being-z-xyi-how-can-i-factorize-the-polynomial-z41-as-a-product-of-real-q/3841256#3841256.